# How to display instances from two different django models on the same template, inside the same table?

Tags: python, django, django-views

In a django app I've created different models and everything looks okay until I try using data from two different models inside the same table.
To sum it up: in the homepage, I need to create a table that contains data from both the models, ordered by date.

The two models I need to display are the following.

models.py

```
class Document(models.Model):
    number = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    assigned = models.BooleanField
    validity_date = models.DateField
    is_issued = models.BooleanField

class Program(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    validity_date = models.DateField
```

Then, I tried to create a view that would allow me to work with different models.

This is my view.py:

```
class BaseView(generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'base/base_list.html'
    context_object_name = 'base_list'

    def get_queryset(self):
         queryset = Document.objects.order_by('due_date')
         return queryset

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(BaseView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['Programs'] = Program.objects.all()
        context['Employees'] = Employee.objects.all()
        return context
```

Now how can I create inside the template a table that shows both the models at once, ordering each entry by validity date (no matter if the entry belongs to Program or to Document)?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to first query both the models, chain them together (Concatenate them) and then order by their shared attribute, that is the `validity_date`. You may do something like:

```
from itertools import chain
documents = Documents.objects.all()
programs = Program.objects.all()
final_combined_list = sorted(chain(documents,programs),key=lambda instance: instance.validity_date)
```

You can now simply pass `final_combine_list` to the template and render it to display it in the manner you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(BaseView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['object_list'] = sorted(
        itertools.chain(Document.objects.all(), Program.objects.all()),
        key=lambda x: x.validity_date
    )
    return context
```